# ggplot reorders categorical variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having trouble figuring out why ggplot reorders my categorical variables

```
xaxis = c('80','90','100')
test = data.frame(x = xaxis, y = c(1,2,3))
ggplot(test, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

I found online that it has something to do with the factor levels and the following code fixes my problem.

```
xaxis = c('80','90','100')
xaxis = factor(xaxis,levels=xaxis)
test = data.frame(x = xaxis, y = c(1,2,3))
ggplot(test, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

But if you go back to the original code.

```
class(xaxis)
[1] "character"
```

Its simply a character vector and I don't see any innate ordering.  Can someone explain what is happening here please?  Do I always have to change my x variable into a factor for ggplot to respect my sequence?

Comment: Thanks for the link.  It didn't come up in my search.  What I don't understand is if I follow his example,  class(x$variable) is 'ordered','factor'.  It makes sense that ggplot follows the order specified.  Mine is simply an unordered vector.  Does ggplot automatically sort my variable before plotting?

Comment: It converts to factor, which sorts automatically by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sort(xaxis)
[1] "100" "80"  "90"
```

Sorting of character vectors is done by a character by character basis - ie it doesn't understand the numerical context of the data.

`ggplot2` will convert character variables to factors and by default factors sort their levels:

```
factor(xaxis)
[1] 80  90  100
Levels: 100 80 90
```

Comment: Actually giving the check to the comment above